# Laravel with Docker: wrong DB selected when testing

Tags: docker, testing, laravel-5, docker-compose, phpunit

My docker containers are as such:

- `worklog_laravel_app` (Laravel app)
- `worklog_laravel_web` (Nginx)
- `worklog_laravel_db` (MySQL)

I have two databases setup in the `worklog_laravel_db` container:

- `worklog`
- `worklog_test`

Right now, I'm in the midst of writing tests for my app via `docker exec -it` `bash` on the `worklog_laravel_app` container.

I've already setup my `env.testing` to have the same vars as `.env`, except:

- `APP_ENV=testing`
- `DB_DATABASE=worklog_test`

But running tests still ends up selecting the local dev DB (`worklog`) instead.

Why is this so? And how do I resolve this?

---

Edit 1:

I verified this by observing the that the seeded data in the `worklog` table being removed after running tests, and the `auto_increments` of those tables changing every time a test is run.

---

Edit 2:

Forgot to mention, my Docker setup follows the one from [DigitialOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-laravel-nginx-and-mysql-with-docker-compose)

---

Edit 3:

My `.env.testing` vars:

```
APP_NAME="Work Log"
APP_ENV=testing
APP_KEY={}
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=worklog_laravel_db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=worklog_test
DB_USERNAME=local
DB_PASSWORD={}

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Comment: If you haven't linked those docker containers / processes, the `worklog_laravel_app` container doesn't know about the others. If you're working with multiple containers, have a look into `docker-compose`.

Comment: Yea the containers are linked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, make sure your testing env is called `.env.testing`, and then make sure in your TestCase.php file that you specify in your TestCase.php file under the `createApplication()` method, you specify this line:

```php
$app->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.testing');
```

Make sure to put that **before** the bootstrap load, otherwise it will not work.  Your createApplication method should look like this:

```php
public function createApplication()
    {
        $app->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.testing');

        $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

        $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

        return $app;
    }
```

Comment: Tried this; it's still using the `worklog` DB over the test one...
Yea, did put line "$app->load..." after line "$app = require...", still not working

Comment: Btw, do I have to change anything in the phpunit.xml config?

Comment: Do I have to restart the docker containers?

Comment: Yes, restart your docker container after making the changes.